# ¿Se puede realizar un un update con con dblink?

Tags: postgresql

Quiero hacer un update de una base de datos a otro con el dblink en postgres como se ve:

```
SELECT * FROM dblink_exec('dbname=sie7','update catalogo_organizaciones set activacion_tablas=0 where rfc= 'LIMJ930210HDZ' ')
```

en postgresql se ejecuta bien pero cuando paso la query a php me a aparece el siguiente error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "LIMJ930210HDZ" LINE 1: ...rganizaciones set activacion_tablas=0 where rfc= 'LIMJ930210... ^

Alguien sabe por qué pasa.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes revisar bien que si este utilizando bien el tipo de comillas cuando lo estas usando en el PHP recuerda "" comillas dobles si el string dentro de estas lleva comillas debes usar comillas simples ''.

Comment: Esta es mi consulta en php segun yo todo esta bien    $this->db_sie7->query("SELECT * FROM dblink_exec('dbname=sie7','update catalogo_organizaciones set activacion_tablas=0 where rfc= ''$rfc'' ')");